# Signing Page Content and Scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, encryption

We are making a client / server password management and sharing app, where the encryption and decryption is done via Javascript (probably [OpenPGPJS](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs)).

Now the questions is how to distribute the app. We thought about browser plugins, because they can be signed. But then we have to make a plugin for each browser.

The attack vector is as follows: If a cracker can get access to the web server that is distributing the app, he could also inject code to sniff the decrypted code.

Idea:

Distribute a app.html to the users which contains the full OpenPGPJS code as well as our public key. Next, download Javascript and HTML parts plus PGP signatures of each file and verify them against the bundled key.

**Edit** The app.html should be distributed via a second way of course and authenticated.

This way we can easily upgrade the app (as long as we do not need to make fixes to the loader code).

The web-app itself would be written in AngularJS.

Would that work?

Is there maybe already a library / pattern which solves something like this?

Comment: *"If a cracker can get access to the web server that is distributing the app, he could also inject code to sniff the decrypted code."* - Yes, this can always be done if you're requiring a connection to download the code. What makes you think that the initial verification code works as expected? You can't do anything about that other than create a proper browser extension, which would still be vulnerable to some extent.

Comment: @ArtjomB. The `app.html` should be distributed via another way and stored *permanently* on the client.